# Calling WCF service dynamically with ref and out parameters

Tags: wcf, dynamic

I have gone through following references and found that a WCF service can be called dynamically. But, i have not been able to call a service (method) accepting parameters as **ref** and **out**.

[Calling a WCF service from a client without having the contract interface](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328552/Calling-a-WCF-service-from-a-client-without-having#)

[Dynamic Programming with WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx)

[Dynamically Invoking Web Services... With WCF This Time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/01/20/dynamically-invoking-web-services-with-wcf-this-time.aspx)

[Invoking WCF Service without adding a Service Reference.](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2009/01/invoking-wcf-service-without-service.html)

Is there any way to make such call with **ref** and **out** parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Invoking WCF Service without adding a Service Reference.](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2009/01/invoking-wcf-service-without-service.html) works greate provided i know the  Contract. So i added the web reference first, copied the generated proxy into actual project and then removed the web refernce and simply called the method as

```
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress epAddr = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.0.233/GMS/GMSService.svc");
            GMSContract.IGMSService _interface = ChannelFactory<GMSContract.IGMSService>.CreateChannel(binding, epAddr);         
...
            bool r = _interface.MyGMSMethod(..., ref ..., out ..., out ...);
```